# Show modal window for 1 second

Tags: c++, winapi, showmodaldialog, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a mainForm and dialogForm. I want to show modal dialogForm for 1 second and it should close **programmatically**. I tried this code:

```
//onButtonClick()
{
dialogForm->ShowModal();
Sleep(1000);
dialogForm->ModalResult =  mrOk;
dialogForm->Close();
}
```

I tried also without `Sleep(1000);`, but it just doesn't close the form. How properly to close this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowModal()` returns when the modal form is closed. That is one of the key points about a form being modal. So, only after the form is closed does your program call `Sleep()`.

Instead you need to add a timer, with interval of 1000ms, to the form. Start the timer when the form is shown. When the timer fires, close the form.

Note that you should never call `Sleep()` from the UI thread because this stops the UI thread processing messages and thus makes the program become unresponsive.